# Adding a legend to a ggplot2 plot which contains multiple elements

Tags: r

This is a similar question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496984/how-to-add-legend-to-ggplot-manually-r) however I could not get their solution to work for me.  I want to add a legend to a ggplot2 plot, when using more than one independent data frame to generate the plot.

Here is an example based on the data sets available in R:

```
a=longley
b=iris
a$scaled=scale(a$Unemployed,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
b$scaled=scale(b$Sepal.Length,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
ggplot () + 
    geom_density(data=a,aes(x=scaled),fill="red",alpha=0.25) +
    geom_density(data=b,aes(x=scaled),fill="blue",alpha=0.25) +
    scale_colour_manual("",breaks=c("a","b"),values=c("red","blue"))
```

The plot produced looks like this:
[image: Plot produced]
ie. no legend.

How would I add a legend to this?

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027016/missing-legend-with-ggplot2-and-geom-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very minor syntactic change required.  Move the `fill=` part into the aes() statement in each geom.

```
a=longley
b=iris
a$scaled=scale(a$Unemployed,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
b$scaled=scale(b$Sepal.Length,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
ggplot () + 
    geom_density(data=a,aes(x=scaled,fill="red"),alpha=0.25) +
    geom_density(data=b,aes(x=scaled,fill="blue"),alpha=0.25)
```

This should work alone and will give you the default r color scheme.  Or, if you really want to change the colors from the defaults, you can add the manual scale.  However, since you want the scale to apply to the `fill` parameter, make sure to specify `scale_fill_manual` rather than `scale_colour_manual`.

```
ggplot () + 
    geom_density(data=a,aes(x=scaled,fill="red"),alpha=0.25) +
    geom_density(data=b,aes(x=scaled,fill="blue"),alpha=0.25) +
    scale_fill_manual("",breaks=c("a","b"),values=c("red","blue"))
```

If you wanted to change the colors of the lines you would do that with the `color` aesthetic and would then be able to use the `scale_color_manual` or `scale_colour_manual` (same thing) option.

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_density(data=a, aes(x=scaled, fill="red", color="yellow"), alpha=0.25) +
    geom_density(data=b, aes(x=scaled, fill="blue", color="green"), alpha=0.25) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("yellow", "green"))
```